# jQuery: toggle header class on scroll and if page is not at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery snippet which toggles the class `tinyHead` on the header when the user scrolls the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).on('scroll touchmove', function () {
        $('#header').toggleClass('tinyHead', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
    });
});
```

This works with no problems, however, if a user refreshes the page after they have scrolled down then when the page reloads the `tinyHead` class is not on the header. If they then scroll the class toggles on.

What I need is for the script to check if the page is at the top of the viewport and if it isn't then to add the class `tinyHead`

Thank you

Comment: Really annoys me when people down vote questions and don't say why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal, your callback function is never executed if the user doesn't `scroll` or `touchmove` or does whatever event you attached your function to.

You have to trigger the attached callback function at least once, you can do it simply by faking a scroll event just after doing the binding:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).on('scroll touchmove', function () {
        $('#header').toggleClass('tinyHead', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
    }).scroll();  // << Add this
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to execute the function on page load (or DOM ready), *in addition* to calling it during scroll or touchmove events. Instead of repeating the function twice, you can do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var tinyHead = function() {
        $('#header').toggleClass('tinyHead', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
    }

    // Call tinyHead() when DOM is ready / upon page load
    tinyHead();

    // Call tinyHead() when scroll or touchmove events are registered
    $(window).on('scroll touchmove', tinyHead);
});
```

---

p/s: On a side note, you might want to look into [throttling your scroll event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) — some browsers "overfire" the event (i.e. calling it too frequently). Since `tinyHead()` is a rather lightweight function, I personally don't think throttling the scroll event will bring about massive performance improvements, but if your `tinyHead()` function is computationally heavy, you might want to look into this option :)